# Arch: Is yaourt deprecated?

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, pacman, yaourt

I came across [this article](https://itsfoss.com/best-aur-helpers/) saying that yaourt is deprecated.
I wanted to look up more information about that on Arch Wiki, but found that yaourt is not listed on the [list of AUR helpers](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR_helpers), which is bewildering.

Is yaourt really deprecated? If so, what are the reasons? Is there an official announcement on Arch Wiki?
And what are some widely recognized alternatives to yaourt among those listed on the page just cited (if not all of them)?

Comment: https://github.com/archlinuxfr/yaourt/issues/382#issuecomment-475039781

Comment: @muru That's not a comment!  That's an answer!  Please post an answer, ping me [at]Fabby and I'll come back and upvote! **;-)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Yaourt has been [removed from the Aur](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/?O=0&K=yaourt).

If you really want a Aur helper, please choose one on the list [of the Aur helpers](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR_helpers) (I would personally recommend YaY).

Answer (score 1):

`Yaourt` was removed from the official servers of Arch Linux by serious security problems. Die.

It can no longer -or should not be- download from official repositories, and it's not safe to do it by any other means.

I recommend switching to safer alternatives for `AUR` packages, like `aurman`.

Links of interest:

- [Yaourt is Dead! Use These Alternatives for AUR in Arch Linux](https://itsfoss.com/best-aur-helpers/)
- [Remove yaourt from [archlinuxfr] repo](https://github.com/archlinuxfr/yaourt/issues/209)
- [Arch Wiki - AUR helpers](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR_helpers)
- [Archero ¡Deja de usar Yaourt! ¡Usa aurman!](https://securityhacklabs.net/forum/distribuciones-gnulinux/archlinux/2018-06-20/archero-deja-de-usar-yaourt-usa-aurman) (Spanish)

**Update with `aurman` installation:**

You can install `aurman` with the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /tmp
gpg --recv-key 465022E743D71E39
git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/aurman.git
cd aurman
makepkg -si
sudo sed -i '/^#Color/s/^#//' /etc/pacman.conf
aurman -Syu
```

The use of `aurman` is more simple that `yaourt`, and very similar to `pacman`.